# Preventing a textbox from recursively calling textchanged

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, textbox

I am error checking user input in a text box using the following code:

```
Private Sub txtDeadLoadFactor_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDeadLoadFactor.TextChanged
        Dim invalidEntry As Boolean
        If IsNumeric(txtDeadLoadFactor.Text) And Not txtDeadLoadFactor.Text = vbNullString Then
            If Not txtDeadLoadFactor.Text > 0 Then
                invalidEntry = True
            End If
        Else
            invalidEntry = True
        End If
        If invalidEntry Then
            MsgBox("Please only enter numeric data greater than 0 in all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Invalid Input!")
            txtDeadLoadFactor.Text = vbNullString
            invalidEntry = False
        Else
            gDeadLoadFactor = txtDeadLoadFactor.Text
        End If
    End Sub
```

The message box pops up twice on invalid entry. This is due to setting the textbox.text back to a nullstring. I don't know how to prevent that from happening, also if anyone could help clean this messy code up it'd be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to leave the Sub if the text equals vbNullString. Put this line at the beginning of the Sub:

```
If txtDeadLoadFactor.Text = vbNullString then Exit Sub
```

Given that the user may empty the box manually, it would be better if the popup didn't validate empty fields.

EDIT: This refactored code may help you:

```
If txtDeadLoadFactor.Text = vbNullString then Exit Sub
If Not(IsNumeric(txtDeadLoadFactor.Text)) OrElse txtDeadLoadFactor.Text <= 0 then
    MsgBox("Please only enter numeric data greater than 0 in all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Invalid Input!")
    txtDeadLoadFactor.Text = vbNullString
    Exit Sub
End If

gDeadLoadFactor = txtDeadLoadFactor.Text
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't do this. Been a long day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the text to blank anyway? Just leave the text as it is with the error message box, that way the user knows what input is not allowed and will get the same result if they try it again (i.e. consistency, whereas if you change the input for them, then they get a different error when they click submit again). Just my two cents.